# How to fix the disappearing word from the Jlabel when I implement a different class for the second level of my game?

Tags: java, swing

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class trial extends JPanel {
    JFrame frame;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button3;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel label;
    JPanel buttonPanel;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        trial t = new trial();
        t.go();
    }

    public void go() {
        JPanel buttonPanel= new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 70);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GAME");
        JLabel label=new JLabel("Green");
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setForeground(Color.blue);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("blue");
        buttonPanel.add(button1);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("red");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("green");
        buttonPanel.add(button2);
        buttonPanel.add(button3);
        frame.add(button1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(button3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(button2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        button1.addActionListener(new Level2());
        button1.setForeground(Color.black);
        button2.addActionListener(new Gameover());
        button2.setForeground(Color.black);
        button3.addActionListener(new Gameover());
        button1.setBackground(Color.white);
        button2.setBackground(Color.white);
        button3.setBackground(Color.white);
        button3.setForeground(Color.black);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(buttonPanel);

    }
    public void goone(){
        JPanel buttonPanel= new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 70);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("GAME");
        JLabel label=new JLabel("Black");
        label.setFont(font);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setForeground(Color.red);
        JButton button1 = new JButton("red");
        buttonPanel.add(button1);
        JButton button2 = new JButton("blue");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("green");
        buttonPanel.add(button2);
        buttonPanel.add(button3);
        frame.add(button1, BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.add(button3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.add(button2, BorderLayout.EAST);
        button1.addActionListener(new Level2());
        button1.setForeground(Color.black);
        button2.addActionListener(new Gameover());
        button2.setForeground(Color.black);
        button3.addActionListener(new Gameover());
        button1.setBackground(Color.white);
        button2.setBackground(Color.white);
        button3.setBackground(Color.white);
        button3.setForeground(Color.black);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.getContentPane().add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(buttonPanel);
        repaint();
    }
    class Gameover implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            System.out.println("gameover");


        }
    }
    class Level2 implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            goone();


        }
}
```

The label disappears after I call another similar method which is the second level of my game.This is the first label with minor changes.The buttons change but the label with the name of the color disappears.In my game, the user selects the color in the word(label)and not the word itself.If a wrong button is pressed then 'game over' is printed out. Else the person progresses to level2.In this, the word in the label changes. The options change as well.Now I am trying to figure out a way where the game progresses to level 2 without the label disappearing
}

Comment: Are yout alking about `JLabel label=new JLabel("Black")`? I can see that

Comment: yes, the label disappears

Comment: I can see it when pressing the blue button

Comment: How do i fix it

Comment: Your layout is broken, default Layout for JFrame is borderlayout and you never stated which is where... I suggest to put the label at the center of the panel (the one which manage buttons). Don't put buttons both in panel and frame!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your layout is broken, you may want something like:

```
public void go() {
    JPanel buttonPanel= new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 70);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("GAME");
    JLabel label=new JLabel("Green");
    label.setFont(font);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setForeground(Color.blue);
    JButton button1 = new JButton("blue");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("red");
    JButton button3 = new JButton("green");
    buttonPanel.add(button1,BorderLayout.WEST);
    buttonPanel.add(button2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    buttonPanel.add(button3,BorderLayout.EAST);
    buttonPanel.add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    button1.addActionListener(new Level2());
    button2.addActionListener(new Gameover());
    button3.addActionListener(new Gameover());
    button1.setForeground(Color.black);
    button2.setForeground(Color.black);
    button3.setForeground(Color.black);
    button1.setBackground(Color.white);
    button2.setBackground(Color.white);
    button3.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(buttonPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```